# Azure Functions Runtime v2 - for on-prem operations

Tags: azure, azure-functions

does anybody know whether the local version of the Azure Functions Runtime will be finalized (and upgraded to v2) any time soon?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-install

I mean the dev CLI works fine - but I am actually talking about operating Functions on-prem in production (not in the Azure cloud).

Thanks.

Comment: Looking into this to see if there is a date we can share.  Right now v2 is in preview so it may be gated on when it comes out of preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we're continuing to work on the Azure Functions Runtime preview, our on-premises offering to enable Azure Functions workloads to be run on-premises.  We are working on bringing the v2 runtime to the on-premises preview but I do not have a date I can share for the next preview release.  I will update this question when I am able to share the date.

Thanks

Andrew